# Set one row fields as a multiplication of 2 others

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a such a structure of SQL table

```
Id    A     B    C   D
1     1     5    6   25
2     2     10   5   25
3     3     7    4   25
4     1     6    5   26
5     2     10   5   26
6     3     8    3   26
```

I want to write a script, which will update all the **B & C columns** in the rows with **A=3** with the value of multiplication of the **A = 1 and A = 2** (for the same value of **D** column)

So the result should be

```
Id    A     B    C   D
1     1     5    6   25
2     2     10   5   25
3     3     50   30  25
4     1     6    5   26
5     2     10   5   26
6     3     60   25  26
```

How can I write such a code in SQL?

Comment: will the values of A always be 1,2,3?

Comment: Yes, they can be 1,2,3,4 and 5. But the script should only change the rows with value 3.

Comment: And set them to Row1 value * Row2 value

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One possible way is joining table to itself twice:

```
update T3
set
    T3.B = T1.B * T2.B,
    T3.C = T1.C * T2.C
from [Table] T3
    join [Table] T1 on T1.A = 1 and T1.D = T3.D
    join [Table] T2 on T2.A = 2 and T2.D = T3.D
where
    T3.A = 3
```