# UPDATE with non-CLR product aggregate results in off-by-one

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, aggregate

I was answering another question and ran into a strange outcome - the output of a product aggregate (without CLR) was different when used in a SELECT vs UPDATE.

This is simplified from the original question to minimally reproduce the problem:

```
GroupKey    RowIndex    A
----------- ----------- -----------
25          1           5
25          2           6
25          3           NULL
26          1           3
26          2           4
26          3           NULL
```

The goal is for each group key to update the `A` column of each row with a `RowIndex = 3` to the product of the `A` columns of each row with `RowIndex IN (1, 2)`, so this would produce the following changes:

```
GroupKey    RowIndex    A
----------- ----------- -----------
25          3           30
26          3           12
```

So this is the code I used:

```
UPDATE T SET
    A = Products.Product
FROM @Table T
    INNER JOIN (
        SELECT
            GroupKey,
            EXP(SUM(LOG(A))) AS Product
        FROM @Table
        WHERE RowIndex IN (1, 2)
        GROUP BY
            GroupKey
    ) Products
        ON Products.GroupKey = T.GroupKey
WHERE T.RowIndex = 3
SELECT * FROM @Table WHERE RowIndex = 3
```

Which then produced the off-by-one results:

```
GroupKey    RowIndex    A
----------- ----------- -----------
25          3           29
26          3           12
```

If I just run the sub-query, I see the correct values.

```
GroupKey    Product
----------- ----------------------
25          30
26          12
```

Here's the full script to make it easy to play with. I can't figure out where the off-by-one is coming from.

```
DECLARE @Table TABLE (GroupKey INT, RowIndex INT, A INT)
INSERT @Table VALUES (25, 1, 5), (25, 2, 6), (25, 3, NULL), (26, 1, 3), (26, 2, 4), (26, 3, NULL)

SELECT * FROM @Table

SELECT
    GroupKey,
    EXP(SUM(LOG(A))) AS Product
FROM @Table
WHERE RowIndex IN (1, 2)
GROUP BY
    GroupKey

UPDATE T SET
    A = Products.Product
FROM @Table T
    INNER JOIN (
        SELECT
            GroupKey,
            EXP(SUM(LOG(A))) AS Product
        FROM @Table
        WHERE RowIndex IN (1, 2)
        GROUP BY
            GroupKey
    ) Products
        ON Products.GroupKey = T.GroupKey
WHERE T.RowIndex = 3
SELECT * FROM @Table WHERE RowIndex = 3
```

Here are some references I came across:

- Non-CLR Aggregate: http://michaeljswart.com/2011/03/the-aggregate-function-product/
- Original question: [Set one row fields as a multiplication of 2 others](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31341659/set-one-row-fields-as-a-multiplication-of-2-others#31341659)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd say that this cute "PRODUCT" aggregate is inherently unreliable if you want to work with `int`s - [`EXP`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179857.aspx) and [`LOG`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190319.aspx) are only defined against the `float` type and so we get rounding errors creeping in.

Why they're not *consistently* appearing, I couldn't say, except to suggest that different queries may cause changes in evaluation orders.

As a simpler example of how this can go wrong:

```
select CAST(EXP(LOG(5)) as int)
```

Can produce `4`. `EXP` and `LOG` together will produce a value that is *just* less than `5`, but of course when converting to `int`, SQL Server always truncates rather than applying any rounding.

Comment: Of course, this also means that `round` would help a bit. It's still unreliable, though.

Comment: It is interesting though in my example if I just change the data type of my table to FLOAT, the rounding error does not occur, but a simple cast/convert to float before the `LOG` doesn't help.

Comment: @JasonW - the rounding error does occur, but for *display*, a `float` sufficiently close to `30` will be converted to the *string* `30`, whereas when we ask to convert that `float` to `int`, things are a little stricter.